# what happens if iron clamp is attached to a copper pipe to a wall?

Tags: redox, oxidation-state, organic-oxidation

I'm guessing its not a good idea, since iron will then corrode easily (also depending on the location and environment), Although copper do not rust it will increase the rate of it from oxidizing. plus with the addition of replacing iron clamp quite often.

Or does copper aids in iron???

Comment: Your question is not clear. If an iron clamp attached to it creates so many problems, then don't attach it. Please describe your problem more explicitly. Also you can consider non-corrosive options like plastic or rubber (I'm not a plumber, so not sure if those are actually viable alternatives).

Comment: The question does not state whether the two metals (electrodes?) are immersed in an electrolyte. As stated, I see no problem.

Comment: You now have an iron clamp attached to a copper pipe on the wall. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

As you state, [iron will  corrode more rapidly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion#/media/File:Corros%C3%A3o_de_ferro_por_sacrif%C3%ADcio_em_contacto_com_cobre.jpg) in contact with a more "noble" metal, e.g. copper. That is why plastic pipe hangers ("clamps") may be used. Also, iron pipe hangers are sold with rubber inserts, both to reduce vibration conducted to the wall and to reduce this [galvanic corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_corrosion).

Comment: Since iron is less noble than copper (in the electrochemical series), the former will act as *sacrificial anode*.

Answer (score 0):

If is is dry - nothing. However even in a typical wall temperature changes could possible cause condensation which would preferentially corrode the steel ( "iron" is rare today). I had a house once with emt ( galvanized steel thin wall tubing for electric wiring). Because of an unusual heating situation, moisture condensed in the emt in the walls. The zinc galvanizing was completely corroded away in some locations, the steel was ugly but no significant metal loss.